# What is the utility of `Tensor` (as opposed to `EagerTensor`) in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow 2.0, the main "tensors" we see are in fact `EagerTensors` (`tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor` to be more precise):

```py
x = [[2.]]
m = tf.matmul(x, x)
type(m)
# returns tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

But, in some cases, we have the symbolic `Tensor` object (`tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`), as in TF1.X.
For example in keras:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
type(model.outputs[0])
# returns tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor
```

So, what are the use for these symbolic:`tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` in Tensorflow:

- In the TF library internals: Keras is at least using these tensors, but is it used at other places (which are using a graph, like tf.function, or tf.data.Dataset)?
- In the API: is there an actual use for end-users of these?

Answer (score 8):

> In the TF library internals: Keras is at least using these tensors, but is it used at other places (which are using a graph, like tf.function, or tf.data.Dataset)?

Well, yes. Your instinct is correct here. `EagreTensor` represents a tensor who's value has been calculated in eager mode whereas `Tensor` represents a tensor node in a graph that may not yet have been calculated.

> In the API: is there an actual use for end-users of these?

Well, on some level we use them all the time. We create keras models, tf.data.Dataset pipelines etc. but, really, for the vast majority of use-cases we don't tend to instantiate or interact directly with the `Tensor` object itself though so probably just want to not worry about the object type and consider them to be an implementation detail internal to tensorflow.